# How to get html from url AFTER ajax on webpage has finished

Tags: html, ajax, swift, web-scraping, nsurlsessiondatatask

I'm writing an app in Swift 3.0 and I'm trying to scrape data from the search results of a webpage. I perform the search by including the search query as a parameter in the url, but the  html that's getting returned to me has no results. I believe this is because the ajax on the webpage has not finished and populated the html with the search results by the time the html is returned to my app.

### Question

How do I wait for the search results to load before getting the html?

**EDIT:**
URL: https://uscdirectory.usc.edu/web/directory/faculty-staff/#basic=a

This url performs a search on the USC directory for the character 'a'. The html in my browser on my MacBook includes these tags:

```
<tbody>(Search results are here)</tbody>
```

but in my app the html that is returned to me has nothing:

```
<tbody></tbody>
```

This is because the webpage initially has no search results, and then some time later the ajax finishes and the table body is populated. How do I use a URLSessionDataTask object in Swift to wait until the ajax finishes and ONLY THEN give me the html, such that I actually get the search results?

Comment: Be sure to make your question conform to [mcve]. It's hard for us to provide guidance when we don't have any code to start from.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu is this any better?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround solution that I devised is unpleasant but functional. I created a WKWebView off screen and loaded the webpage I was interested in. I used a Timer to wait some arbitrary number of seconds for the javascript on the page to finish and then I retrieved the html from the webview

Answer (score 0):

You can use property ajaxComplete() to fix this.

Ex:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    //your code to render HTML
});
```

It will render your HTML only when ajax request is complete.

Comment: The webpage I'm querying isn't mine, so I can't change it. Any other work around? I'm looking for a solution on the Swift side, because I am writing an app in Swift to scrape data from this webpage and right now it's not working for this reason

Comment: He's looking for Swift code that will execute after the ajax is complete